# Best Practice - Javascript Animation using timed background image changes

Tags: javascript, animation, setinterval, adobe-animate

I'm fairly new to coding / javascript and was wanting to get feedback on a method I'm using. I got frustrated trying to import multiple adobe animate html5/javascript files so I reverted to:

- exporting the animations frame by frame (.png)
- using javascript to call a local file and change the 'src' of a div given a specific interval

filename1 - is the folder file
filename - is the .png filename

Is this bad practice or is there better more efficient way to do this? I plan on having it triggered in an interactive site when users click on different areas of an image. Worried the constant calling of files could be an issue and I'm unsure what would happen if someone triggered a new animation while one was still running?

So far it seems to be running okay, it does 'jitter' every once and a while if I interact with the site while an animation is running.

```
function playTargetAnimation (filename1,filename) {
      let i = 1;
      $('#'+filename1).attr('src', "images/" + filename1 +"/" + filename +"/" + filename + '0001' + ".png");
      $('#'+filename1).show();
      let runAnim = setInterval(function(){
      let imgCnt = "00" + ("0" + i).slice(-2);
       $('#'+filename1).attr('src', "images/" + filename1 +"/" + filename +"/" + filename + imgCnt + ".png");
       console.log('src', "images/" + filename +"/" + filename + imgCnt + ".png");
       i++;
       if(i === 41) {
         clearInterval(runAnim);
       };
     }, 25);
  }
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest looking into requestAnimationFrame rather than using intervals. If you use intervals then the animation can become very choppy if the process loses priority or there's a lot of work going on you're not in control of.  
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Thanks! I'll certainly take a look and read through that.

Comment: @MarkTaylor looking at the requestAnimationFrame doc, I understand the function but how can I also pass the filenames to the function? Is it as simple as adding to the param's? (timestamp, filename1, filename2)? worried that would affect the callback.

Comment: @MarkTaylor just incorporated the "step" function in the mozilla example within my function and all works great. THANKS! For my knowledge, how does the "step" function mozilla shows know how much time to display in-between "frames"?

Comment: Roughly speaking the browser will run at as many frames per second as it thinks it can handle - if it's not being stressed this is usually 60-70. Assuming you have a 1 second animation that has 20 frames what you want to do is take a timestamp at the start of the animation, then, during the requestAnimationFrame you calculate the difference between that and the current timestamp and then fetch and display the correct frame. Now if the browser is slow you might 'skip' a frame doing this but it'll still LOOK much smoother because your animation will still take exactly 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@import "compass/css3";

.hi {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: url("https://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
  
}
.hi:hover{
  animation: play .8s steps(10);  
}

@keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position:    0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
<p>↑ mouse over to view animation</p>
<div><img src="https://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png" /></div>
```

If you prefer javascript, requestAnimationFrame is much better than setInterval.

While my suggestion is **css3 animation** [doc in mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function#steps()):

First composite all those frame pictures into one picture file regularly.

Then write css with "animation" and "steps function".

```css
.hi:hover{
  animation: play .8s steps(10);  
}

@keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position:    0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -500px;
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you create a single .png file that can reference multiple steps/frames in the animation? I kept trying to export my animation (adobe animate) in that type of format but it just kept spitting out the frame by frame .png files? I tried referencing the root (everything before '001', '002', etc.) but it kept giving a reference error (probably cause that file doesn't exist).

Comment: I'm going to go the JS route, but I marked this as correct as it appears to be a better method than what I did regardless.

Comment: I am not familiar with adobe animation. there are many ways and tools to combine pictures. I can show your an easy way to generate picture file by canvas, click right button then you get a png: https://codepen.io/dunhuang/pen/rNeBxNe